# Handling ExecuteFilesInUse with Retry and resolving used files

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm having a custom Managed Bootstrapper Application for my installer and I am hooking into the `ExecuteFilesInUse` event to show a UI to the user. In this UI I list the processes provided in the event and 2 buttons: Retry and Cancel. Everything seems to work fine. When I lock some of my files and I press retry, it checks again for files in use. If I press cancel the installation aborts. When I resolve the files in use by closing all applications the installation/uninstallation continues when pressing retry.

But then the problem starts: The `msiexec.exe` process gets stuck. It utilizes 1 CPU core at 100%. Almost as if it is in an endless loop doing nothing. The logfiles do not contain any details that something is done and nothing happens.

My code looks like this:

```
// bootstrapper.ExecuteFilesInUse += Bootstrapper_ExecuteFilesInUse;

private void Bootstrapper_ExecuteFilesInUse(object sender, ExecuteFilesInUseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler<ExecuteFilesInUseEventArgs>(Bootstrapper_ExecuteFilesInUse), sender, e);
        return;
    }

    IList<string> files = e.Files;
    if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
    {
        e.Result = Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.Result.Ignore;
        return;
    }

    var hasEmptyRecords = e.Files.Any(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
    if (hasEmptyRecords)
    {
        e.Result = Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.Result.Retry;
        return;
    }

    var window = new FilesInUseWindow();
    window.DataContext = new FilesInUseViewModel(e.Files);
    var result = window.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        e.Result = Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.Result.Retry;
    }
    else
    {
        Cancelled = true;
        e.Result = Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.Result.Cancel;
    }
}
```

```

The default WiX bootstrapper by default only provides the options to close them automatically or to schedule a reboot afterwards. But I want the user to manually close everything clean and then continue with the installation. I also attached the debugger ot my MBA to check if ti might be still firing the event

Is this workflow not supported or am I simply doing something wrong here?

> Update: I decided also to file an [issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5790) on the Wix project page as I was able to reproduce this hang also on a fresh project.

Comment: You verified that your not getting repeatedly called and exiting with a Retry result code set because you found empty strings in the "file" list?

Comment: Yes, I verified that. I added logs and also added `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch` statements to the method to check this.